# PFQuery receiving different data order

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am using the following code to retrive some data, but the problem is every time I run the application I am receiving my data in a different order:

```
[PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *geoPoint, NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {

        NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

        __block PFQuery *query = [[PFQuery alloc] initWithClassName:@"orders"];

        [query setLimit:25];

        [query whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:geoPoint withinKilometers:kilometers];
        [query whereKey:@"createdAt" lessThanOrEqualTo:currentDate];

        [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (objects.count > 0) {

                [self.flebData removeAllObjects];
                [self.flebData addObjectsFromArray:objects];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    [self.tableView reloadData];

                    [self.tableView.pullToRefreshView stopAnimating];
                    // once refresh, allow the infinite scroll again
                    self.tableView.showsInfiniteScrolling = YES;

                });
            }
            query = nil;
        }];
    }
}];
```

Is this a bug or is something wrong in my code ?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this.  You do receive the newest items first, so it depends on what/when new data is inserted.  Perhaps an example of your output and your expected output would help

Comment: @Paulw11 the problem is order by is not working well, some time i am receiving the newest item and some time not .

Comment: This seems to describe your problem - https://parse.com/questions/pfquery-sort-and-limit-issue-want-sort-limit-getting-limit-sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [PFQuery docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKey:nearGeoPoint:), most location constraints, specifically `whereKey:nearGeoPoint:`, `whereKey:nearGeoPoint:withinMiles:`, `whereKey:nearGeoPoint:withinKilometers:`, and `whereKey:nearGeoPoint:withinRadians:`, force the query to return results "sorted by distance (nearest to farthest) from the reference point"; and so if your location changes at all, the result order can change too.

But the location constraint [`whereKey:withinGeoBoxFromSouthwest:toNortheast:`](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKey:withinGeoBoxFromSouthwest:toNortheast:) does not force any distance sorting algorithm upon the results. So, as the answer Paulw11 linked to in his comment points out, you could use that method along with the `[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];` to get the result order you desire.

The potential problem for you though, is that the `whereKey:withinGeoBoxFromSouthwest:toNortheast:` method checks within a square, the `whereKey:nearGeoPoint:withinKilometers:` checks within a circle radius, and they're generally different methods.

So if finding points within that circular kilometer radius *and* having the results sorted in the order in which they were created is important to you, perhaps you should sort your `results` *after* they're found with the query, ex:

```
PFQuery *query = [[PFQuery alloc] initWithClassName:@"orders"];

[query setLimit:25];

[query whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:geoPoint withinKilometers:kilometers];
[query whereKey:@"createdAt" lessThanOrEqualTo:currentDate];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    if (objects.count > 0) {

        createdAtDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"createdAt" ascending:NO];
        sortDescriptor = [NSArray arrayWithObject:createdAtDescriptor];
        self.flebData = [objects sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptor];
```

Comment: The concept of sorting after doesn't really work because I do not get all the results that are the latest.

Comment: @KyleBrowning If you're only sorting 25 items, the sort should take milliseconds and I doubt the data will change much during that time...

Comment: Its not about the time, its about the results of the call. If I make the call to get all objects that are near this geopoint, and my results are more than 100, it starts dropping off results that are not as close because the distance is applied. I started using,  whereKey:withinGeoBoxFromSouthwest:toNortheast: so its fine